# I would like to have a custom inspect function for use with util.inspect in node.js to treat arrays specially

Tags: node.js, customization, inspect

Given `var a = {a:'a', b:'b', c:[1,2,3], d:{ d1:{ d2:{ d3:[1,2,3] }}}};` I would like to get the following output from `console.log( util.inspect( a, {depth:null}));`

```
{ a: 'a',
  b: 'b',
  c: Array[3],
  d: { d1: { d2: { d3: Array[3] } } } }
```

I tried the following but all I get is `undefined`

```
a.inspect = function(depth){
  var self = this;
  Object.keys(self).forEach( function(key){
    if(Array.isArray(self[key])){
      return key+': Array['+self[key].length+']';
    }else{
      return util.inspect(self[key]);
    }
  });
};
```

The [documentation at node.js](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_custom_inspect_function_on_objects) isn't very helpful, and all of the pages I've found on Google merely parrot the node.js text.

Comment: I'm no Node expert, but is `this` (and thus `self`) actually what you think it is? Why don't you just refer to `a` instead?

Comment: The example in the node.js documentation uses `this.name` to refer to the object's `name` attribute, so I figured it would follow to use it the same way.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `return` statements refer to the inline function used for iterating over those items, so the `inspect` function doesn't return anything at all.

To fix that, you can iterate over the entries using a (blocking) `for` loop and return from there.

Apart of that, you should accumulate sub-results from each key and only return in the end.

I.e something like (not tested):

```
a.inspect = function(depth) {
  var result = '{';
  for (var key in this) {
    if (Array.isArray(this[key]))
      result += key + ': Array[' + this[key].length + ']';
    else
      result += util.inspect(this[key]);
  }
  result += '}';
  return result;
};
```

Note how you don't need any replacement for `this`, as you're always in the same closure.

Answer (score 0):

Cedric, you are correct that I wasn't returning anything from inspect -- the peril of trying to write code at 4am!  But I can't seem to get rid of using `self=this` because it seems like I have to keep attaching the inspect function to the inner objects.  After further experimentation, I have ended up with something that does not quite format things exactly the way util.inspect does, but it's close enough for my purposes.

```
var util=require('util');
var a = {a:'a', b:'b', c:[1,2,3], d:{ d1:{ d2: { d3:[1,2,3] }}, dd1: { dd2: { dd3: [1,2,3]}}}};
a.inspect = function(depth){
    var self = this;
    var sp = '  ';
    return '{ ' + Object.keys(self).reduce( function(str,key){
        if( key==='inspect' && typeof self[key]==='function' ) return str ;
        if(Array.isArray(self[key])){
            return str+(str?',\n'+sp.repeat(depth+1):'')+key+': Array['+self[key].length+']';
        }else{
            if( typeof self[key] === 'object' ) self[key].inspect=a.inspect ;
            return str+(str?',\n'+sp.repeat(depth+1):'')+key+': '+util.inspect(self[key], {colors:true,depth:null});
        }
    }, '') + ' }'
};
console.log( util.inspect( a, {colors:true,depth:null} ));
```

This requires a version of node that supports the repeat method, otherwise see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat) for a polyfill.  Here is the output:

```
{ a: 'a',
  b: 'b',
  c: Array[3],
  d: { d1: { d2: { d3: Array[3] } },
  dd1: { dd2: { dd3: Array[3] } } } }
```